# Add fee to woocommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a fee to my cart when the customer has a specific billing country. For example Belgium (BE)

I found this code to add a fee by default. 
Could anyone help me with an IF formula or something, so that it is only applied when the billing country = BE ?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge'    );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

$percentage = 0.01;
$surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

Comment: You should share code which you trying to apply.

Comment: You're right :) sorry forgot the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need. Just add BE to the `$county` array (I just did that for you in the code below).

```
/**
 * Add a 1% surcharge to your cart / checkout based on delivery country
 * Taxes, shipping costs and order subtotal are all included in the surcharge amount
 *
 * Change $percentage to set the surcharge to a value to suit
 *
 * Add countries to array('BE'); to include more countries to surcharge
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes for available alpha-2 country codes 
 *
 * Change in_array to !in_array to EXCLUDE the $countries array from surcharges
 *
 * Uses the WooCommerce fees API
 * Add to theme functions.php
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $county     = array('BE');
    $percentage     = 0.01;

    if ( in_array( $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) :
        $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );
    endif;

}
```

source: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/

Comment: Thanks Erik! I've found that code before as well, but it didn't work for me. Somehow when I copy it from your answer, it does work.
Could you perhaps help me further with this code? As I have another question.

Comment: Sure, you can send me your question on LinkedIn